# nginx: how to get url args which contain dash?

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx variable `$arg_` to get url args.

But I find if the url is like 'http://foobar.com/search?field-keywords=foobar', `$arg_field_keywords` or `$arg_field-keywords` don't work.

Can I get `field-keywords` with `$arg_`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had found [article](https://moeffju.net/blog/nginx-automatic-variables-with-dashes), that has a little trick to deal with your problem.

TLDR:

> You can remap variables with complex names by using the map module as follows:

```
map $is_args $http_x_origin {
  default $http_x-origin;
}
```

> The trick is that map does not fully parse its arguments. The syntax is: map A X { default Y; }, with:
>
> - A any variable, preferably one that does not trigger much internal processing (since nginx configs are declarative, using a variable evaluates it). I use $is_args because it’s cheap to calculate.
> - X is the name for the new variable you’ll be creating, i.e. the map target.
> - Y is the name of the variable you want to access. At this point, it can contain dashes, because map does its own parsing.

I guess it might work with `$args_` too.

Comment: I tried it with a `data-foo` querystring parameter and couldn't get it to work with a mapping `$arg_data-foo` (using openresty/1.11.2.4). Any ideas?

Comment: Haven't tried with http_ but with arg_ this is not working...

Comment: This isn't work anymore, see @pva answer and [this](https://marc.info/?l=nginx&m=141589036701879&w=2) link.

Answer (score 3):

While lua may work, we have nginx without lua support. Googling around I found the following answer from the upstream developer

> While this may currently work, I wouldn't recommend relying on  this -
> as this is rather a bug than a desired behaviour.  This  will stop
> working as long as support for multiple variables will  be added to
> map.
>
> Instead, I would recommend to use regexp-based parsing of the  $args
> variable as Francis suggests.  This can be done trivially  with map,
> like this:
>
> ```
> map $args $param_with_dash {
>     "~(^|&)param-name=(?<temp>[^&]+)"  $temp;
> }
> ```

Ref: https://marc.info/?l=nginx&m=141589036701879&w=2

Answer (score 1):

Using openresty/1.11.2.4, the `map` method mentioned in the accepted answer did not work for me. But since openresty comes with the precompiled Lua module, I was able to do it using the following piece of code:

```
set $dataArg '';
set_by_lua_block $dataArg { return ngx.req.get_uri_args()["data-arg"] }
proxy_cache_key $scheme$proxy_host$uri$is_args$dataArg;
```

Answer (score 0):

use map directive to get the value argument a-b

eg:

```
map $args $arg_a_b {
     ~*&?a-b=([^&]*) $1;
     default         "";
}
```

match a-b case insensitive and get the value to $arg_a_b, if not set null

Comment: While this answer generally working, your regex will match any query argument ending with `a-b`, for example `data-b`, etc. More correct is `~*(?:^|&)a-b=([^&]*) $1;` (meaning `a-b` could be at the beginning of the arguments string or after `&` character).