# URL rewriting QUERY_STRING NGINX?

Tags: nginx, query-string

I want to download any file from the host whose last address had the x-oss-process parameter.
i.php?path=$1&x-oss-process=%1
Refer that $1 is the address of the referenced file and %1 is the value of the x-oss-process parameter
Like the link below

https://dl.example.com/img/all/235868.jpg?x-oss-process=image/resize,m_lfit,h_200,w_200/quality,q_60

After referring this address to the following address

i.php?path=img/all/235868.jpg&x-oss-process=image/resize,m_lfit,h_200,w_200/quality,q_60

Now how do I write the nginx code to do this? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the query argument name didn't contain any dash characters, like `x_oss_process` instead of `x-oss-process`, the solution would be much more simple. In that case we could check `$arg_x_oss_process` variable (see [`$arg_name`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_) variable description):

```
if ($arg_x_oss_process) {
    rewrite ^ /i.php?path=$uri;
}
```

The first parameter `^` is a regex that matches any string, [`$uri`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_uri) is a normalized request URI (**without** query arguments). All the query arguments would be added to the rewrited URI (see the [`rewrite`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) directive description):

> If a *replacement* string includes the new request arguments, the previous request arguments are appended after them. If this is undesired, putting a question mark at the end of a replacement string avoids having them appended, for example:
>
> ```
> rewrite ^/users/(.*)$ /show?user=$1? last;
> ```

However since your query argument name contain dashes, the solution will be more complex (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687047/nginx-how-to-get-url-args-which-contain-dash) SO question for additional details). We would need to get the `x-oss-process` query argument value from [`$args`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_args) variable using the [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) directive which shoud be placed **outside** the `server` block:

```
map $args $x_oss_process {
    ~(?:^|&)x-oss-process=([^&]*)    $1;
}

server {
    ...
    if ($x_oss_process) {
        rewrite ^ /i.php?path=$uri;
    }
    ...
}
```

This rewrite rule will rewrite

```
/img/all/235868.jpg?x-oss-process=image/resize,m_lfit,h_200,w_200/quality,q_60
```

request to the

```
/i.php?path=/img/all/235868.jpg&x-oss-process=image/resize,m_lfit,h_200,w_200/quality,q_60
```

This is slighly different from what you've been asked for (note the slash before `img/all/235868.jpg` URI part). I'd rather change `i.php` script to correctly process this, but if you want to strip this slash with nginx itself, you can use second `map` block:

```
map $args $x_oss_process {
    ~(?:^|&)x-oss-process=([^&]*)    $1;
}
map $uri $truncated_uri {
    ~/(.*)                           $1;
}

server {
    ...
    if ($x_oss_process) {
        rewrite ^ /i.php?path=$truncated_uri;
    }
    ...
}
```